# C++ Simple Chat client without boost

Tags: c++, linux, chat

I want to attempt to write a peer to peer chat client that I can use with one of my friends, both of us are running fedora 17.  After doing some reading I want to achieve this by sending the messages through TCP sockets, but I'm not sure what library/libraries I need to use to do this. Honestly I'm a little worn out from trying to get the boost libraries to compile and figuring out how to link them, the whole process just seems unnecessarily complicated to me, seeing that I use vim because I personal prefer not to use IDEs.  Are there any standard C++ libraries that allow for packets of data to be sent from one device to another using tcp sockets?

Comment: You certainly don't need to use boost. Just use the regular socket functions (`socket`, `connect`, `send`, `recv`, and so on).

Comment: Are you not looking for cross platform? Because if not, just use raw linux socket functions? http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

Comment: What does boost have to do with an IDE?

Comment: Check out http://pocoproject.org/ if you are more comfortable with C++ than platform specifics.

Comment: I've heard many people say it's easier to link external libraries with IDEs as opposed to using a rich text editor like vim

Comment: @Ben, No I am not, and I'll check the link out, thanks.  But let's say I was looking for cross platform functionality, would I need to use boost then?

Comment: This is perhaps off topic, but I cannot imagine, that Fedora does not have precompiled boost libraries and an easy way to install the matching headers. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any special libraries, it's all included in the standard C library (libc) that all applications are linked with.

The things you have to do are the usual for a client:

1. Find the IP address of the host ([`getaddrinfo`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo))
2. Create the socket ([`socket`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket))
3. Connect to the server ([`connect`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect))
4. Send and receive data ([`write`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) and [`read`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read))
5. Close connection when done ([`close`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close))

There are many tutorials on network programming on the Internet, almost all of them have examples showing char servers and clients.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need C++ and standard library.
you need to write a program binding to  the concerned port and connectting to another computer by TCP .
Just Sending and receiving msgs through socket connection.